# why is animated curve getting bigger and how to improve that?

Tags: bezier-curves

I animated a simple curve. But unfortunately the curve changes it thickness during animation. How can i stop that? why is it doing that?

[image]

i animated this by just changing the factor start value here:

[image]

blend:

[image]

I tried changing spline type, twist method - didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the *Object Data panel > Shape*, select *2D*:

[image]

And also in *Edit* mode select all, right click, choose *Set Curve Radius* and type 1:

[image]

It works:

[image]